# Is CloudFlare fork of zlib optimized only for amd?

Tags: c, linux, zlib

I extensively use zlib for storing compressed data. While reading data most of the time is spent in inflate_fast and crc32 zlib calls. I am exploring alternatives to speed-up decompression and have two candidates, ipp_zlib from Intel and zlib fork from CloudFlare. I would like to know:

1. Is CloudFlare fork tuned only for AMD processors ? I see that related branch is tagged with 'amd64' at https://github.com/cloudflare/zlib/branches. I have Intel CPUs, so amd64 won't serve the purpose.
2. Whether I need to rewrite data to use CloudFlare version ? If yes, then I will have to ignore this library.

I tried getting both libraries for my Linux machine, but don't see easy way i.e. download link. If anyone installed above, please share instructions to download and build.

Comment: In this case AMD64 simply refers to the architecture itself, the 64-bit extension to the x86 which first developed by AMD but nowadays used by Intel as well. In any event are you tied specifically to (g-)zip or are you free to consider other, potentially more performant, alternatives?

Comment: I use other option such as lzma and planning to experiment with lzo, however most of the existing data is in gzip format.

Comment: Kinda off topic, but interestingly CloudFlare are now starting to experiment with Brotli: https://blog.cloudflare.com/results-experimenting-brotli/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact Cloudflare version of gzip is optimized for Intel Haswell processors. It is 100% gzip compliant.
It is however optimized for high speed compression and does not improve the compression ratio. If you only use statically compressed content, there is not much benefit.

Comment: Vlad, could you please add any link/reference suggesting that CloudFlare is tuned to Haswell ? My use-case is decompression speed however the CloudFlare zlib I compiled from https://github.com/cloudflare/zlib/branches (64 bit Linux, gcc compiler) doesn't show any such speed up.

Comment: I was one of the people working on it, so I know. Like I said it is for fast compression, decompression is fast anyway.

Comment: My use-case writes ones and reads multiple times, so decompression speed is important. Didn't see much decompression speed-up with ipp_zlib either, but that's not official version (I picked up ipp version from https://github.com/jtkukunas/zlib.git). I will update once I have official Intel zlib patch installed.

Answer (score 5):

Neither CloudFlare nor Kukunas' versions of ZLIB help in decompression speedup. They both tuned for faster compression, i.e. deflate. For compression they are good. The "inflate" source code remains untouched.

Though, they must be specifically built. I was able to build them only for 64-bit mode on Linux with Intel compiler and

```
$ export CFLAGS="-D__PCLMUL__ -D__SSE4_2__"
$ ./configure
$ make # (or, $ make shared)
```

commands. And the CPU should have SSE4.2+ architecture. Intel or AMD, whatever.

Though, CFLAGS='-msse4.2 -mpclmul -O3' might work too for GCC compiler, haven't checked.

Comment: This matches with what I experienced i.e. no speed-up in inflate. I am using SSE4.2+ arch.